# Visual Studio Code terminal isn't working

Tags: terminal

[image]

I have installed Visual Studio Code, but I can’t type anything in terminal. How can I correct this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit the gear button in the bottom left and go to the command palette. Type in "terminal" and see if opening a new terminal helps. If not, there are a few other options that come up in the dropdown that you can try that might fix the problem.

Answer (score 13):

Well, I had the same issue and I reset all the changed settings:

1. Click on the engine
2. *Settings*
3. Click on the right three-dot menu
4. Click on show modified settings
5. Then a list of setting will appear put the mouse in the left side of the setting name
6. A little engine shows up. Press *Reset setting*
7. Close and open the Visual Studio Code software

After this the terminal worked again.

Comment: This answer helps me only!

Comment: well, it helps me too ;-)

Comment: Some screenshots would be in order. With [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775) (not a joke).

Answer (score 13):

For me, it worked to close all my Visual Studio Code folders and reopen them.

Comment: This also worked for me. I went and messed around with all the VS code terminal settings, but it wasn't until I closed the windows and totally killed the program did terminal start working correctly.

Comment: This is so simple but it works for me.

Comment: Needed to close all VS Code instances to get it working again.

Answer (score 6):

How I resolved the issue:

1. Open Settings

   [image]
2. Click on this *icon* in the top left of your window [to open the JSON version of settings]

   [image]
3. Remove everything (or find the suspicious setting and delete that line alone!)

   [image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I in actuality had troubleshooted my Visual Studio Code installation.

First press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, search for "Vscode", right-click, and choose **Open File Location**.

Then you will see a file with the *Visual Studio Code* icon. Right click on it, choose properties and on the top-side choose *Compatibility*. Then make sure that *Run Program* in *Compatibility* is turned ***off***.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the value *terminal.integrated.inheritEnv* to true (default) solved the problem for me on [Pop!_OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop!_OS) Linux.

- Go to settings (gear icon in the lower left corner)
- Search for *terminal.integrated.inheritEnv*
- Check it

Answer (score 1):

In my case, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (opening command palette, as [MasterYork42 answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095692/visual-studio-code-terminal-isnt-working/49115311#49115311)) and selecting `Terminal:Clear` worked.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to the 32-bit version *VSCode-win32-ia32-1.43.1*.

Comment: This is already covered by [AnilPatil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095692/visual-studio-code-terminal-isnt-working/60750592#60750592).

Answer (score 1):

Install "System setup" of Visual Studio Code instead of "User setup".

Comment: *How* do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the gear on the left bottom of Visual Studio Code, click on *Settings*. On search settings, type "terminal" and see if there is an assigned value or not. If not, do something like `"terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe"` or whatever for Mac or Linux.

Comment: What do you mean by *"not in not"* (seems incomprehensible)? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49095779/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Thanks @PeterMortensen, it was a mistypo.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with terminal. That terminal does not work in Visual Studio Code.
I fixed this issue by using the 32-bit, version *VSCode-win32-ia32-1.43.1*.

So use the 32-bit application *VSCode-win32-ia32-1.43.1*.

Comment: For [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), presumably?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in the *.vscode* user settings folder. It worked for me.

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe"
```

Comment: `.vscode` is a folder. What file in particular?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on the Visual Studio Code icon on the desktop.
2. Click on *Properties*.
3. Click on *Compatibility setting*.
4. In compatibility mode, uncheck the "Run this program in compatibility mode for..."
5. Click on <kbd>Apply</kbd>.
6. Refresh the desktop and open Visual Studio Code. Boom! It'll work now!

Answer (score 0):

This may well not suffice in every case but, for me, the old fashioned approach of restarting my machine fixed this problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I updated and it started to work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What did you update? Visual Studio Code itself? What version was it before and after? On what platform (e.g., operating system, incl. edition and version)?

Comment: I update the vsc to leatest version and terminal started again

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too using PowerShell as the shell. In my case, I reverted the PowerShell extension to a previous version (causing a terminal load failure), and then reinstalled to the latest version.

[image]

Comment: Latest version of what? PowerShell? Visual Studio Code? Both?

Comment: the PowerShell extension, hence 'I reverted the PowerShell extension to a previous version...'

Answer (score 0):

Below Steps Worked for me:

1. open Preferences > Settings (CTRL+,)
2. search for terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows and set a default (for me Command Prompt)

Comment: Please consider describing the effect of what you propose and why that helps to solve the problem. Try for [answer].

Answer (score -1):

For me, the issue was when I was prompted by VS Code if I wanted it to "auto fetch" every now and then and I said yes.

This added the highlighted setting in my terminal which caused the issues. Once I deleted this, it worked like normal again.

[image: Settings]